# Phonegap wont display google map in the phone

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps, phonegap-plugins

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Geolocation watchPosition() by The Code of a Ninja</title>

    <!-- for mobile view -->
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport'/>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // you can specify the default lat long
        var map,
            currentPositionMarker,
            mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(14.668626, 121.24295),
            map;

        // change the zoom if you want
        function initializeMap()
        {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
               zoom: 18,
               center: mapCenter,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
             });
        }

        function locError(error) {
            // tell the user if the current position could not be located
            alert("The current position could not be found!");
        }

        // current position of the user
        function setCurrentPosition(pos) {
            currentPositionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(
                    pos.coords.latitude,
                    pos.coords.longitude
                ),
                title: "Current Position"
            });
            map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(
                    pos.coords.latitude,
                    pos.coords.longitude
                ));
        }

        function displayAndWatch(position) {

            // set current position
            setCurrentPosition(position);

            // watch position
            watchCurrentPosition();
        }

        function watchCurrentPosition() {
            var positionTimer = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
                function (position) {
                    setMarkerPosition(
                        currentPositionMarker,
                        position
                    );
                });
        }

        function setMarkerPosition(marker, position) {
            marker.setPosition(
                new google.maps.LatLng(
                    position.coords.latitude,
                    position.coords.longitude)
            );
        }

        function initLocationProcedure() {
            initializeMap();
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayAndWatch, locError);
            } else {
                // tell the user if a browser doesn't support this amazing API
                alert("Your browser does not support the Geolocation API!");
            }
        }

        // initialize with a little help of jQuery
        $(document).ready(function() {
            initLocationProcedure();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body style="margin:0; padding:0;">

    <!-- display the map here, you can changed the height or style -->
    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:25em; margin:0; padding:0;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

The above code which run it on my smartphone the google map wont appear but when I run it on localhost it does appear the map and also able to get current location Can anyone help me resolve what is happening

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #map { height: 100%; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}

    </script>
    <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run this code it able to appear the google map in my smartphone I had no idea what is wrong I am so confuse right now can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a google API key:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_apikeys

and then replace YOUR_API_KEY with your API key in the script tag:

```
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: I had try without api key and the bottom one still work charmly but above one cannot work no idea why